# Can a 4.2V cell BMS function with 3.6V cell?

Tags: batteries, bms

I'm trying to make a Li-Ion battery with a BMS (Battery Management System). All BMS I found were for 4.2V cells, so my question is, can I use it for a 3.6V cells?

**Note**: These are LiIon cells, NOT LiFePO4.

Comment: A "3.6 V" Lithium Ion battery will be 4.2 V when fully charged. So, yes.

Comment: How do you even know you need a BMS? If you are making a 1 cell pack you could use a cell with built-in protection. What kind of pack you are making? With what cells? How do you intend to charge it? Please be aware that for some reason, newbies don't understand what they are doing and try to use lithium cells in dangerous ways, that degrade and damage them, and damaged batteries can explode or burst into flames. So I just want to make sure you know you understand what you are doing.

Comment: BMS units are typically designed to work with specific voltage ranges. A BMS designed for 4.2V cells may have voltage thresholds and protections calibrated for that voltage range. Using it with 3.6V cells could result in incorrect voltage readings and potential mismanagement of the battery.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. I need a BMS for protection in case I over or under charge the battery I want to make a 3 series cell battery pack using 18650 Li-Ion batteries, outputting 10.8V. But I've been doing quite a research, so I know how to make it safely.

Comment: What I found in the cell datasheet is that when it is charging termination cycle voltage is of 4.2V, so there should be no problem as StarCat said.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcía Why would you use a BMS for one cell if you are making a 3S pack? You need a BMS intended for making a 3S pack or you damage the cells if they are not balanced.

Comment: you neeed to choose BMS according the battery type and chemistry. LiFePO4 has lower nominal voltage.

Comment: @Justme   In many (most?) cases a 3S BMS is effectively 3 x 1S BMSs in series triggering a single cutoff FET. I agree that a BMS per cell is less desirable, but it probably won't damage anything. With 3 x 1S BMS the first to trigger on over or under voltage will trip its series FET and disable the whole string. || An eg 3S BMS as most usually implemented top balances and will only do do if I in CV mode has fallen to below Ibalance. Ib is usually low compared to I_CC mode so a badly balanced pack will cut off unbalanced. See my answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/698478/3288

Answer (score 0):

They're of different chemistry and their safe operating region are different. 4.2V batteries can either be NMC, LCO or LMO, while 3.6V one is LFP. More info on this you can find here - https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-205-types-of-lithium-ion

You'll need a BMS that can monitor all three cells in series and cut-off even if one is out of its safe operating voltage range. If you use a smart BMS with configurable parameters, you can use the same one by configuring the parameters as required.

As you're getting started, it'll be easier to buy a hardware controlled BMS for 3s LFP battery with the appropriate current rating.

Comment: It **SOUNDS** from the question that he is meaning LiFePOP4 BUT in fact they are LiIon and he is confused by the mean ~= 3.6V of a LiIon cell.  SO your answer would be good if he was using LiFePOP4, but alas, he's not.